# Maven default phase for goal?

Tags: java, maven

From what I understand, in maven, plugin goals can be attached to a lifecycle phase.
What is the default phase, if it isn't defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html correctly, there is no default. If you don't define a default phase, or configure a non-default phase, then the goal won't get executed.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience it depends on the plugin goal.  For example, the [assembly:single](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) goal in the maven-assembly-plugin doesn't list a default phase.  The [source:jar-no-fork](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html) goal binds to the `package` phase by default.  Typically each goal lists the default phase in the **Attributes** section of the documentation.

Another way to tell is to look at the source code (example: [source:jar-no-fork mojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-source-plugin-2.1.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/source/SourceJarNoForkMojo.java?revision=945370&view=markup)).  Look for `@phase` in the class header comment block.

Last but not least: the packaging you select (jar, war, ear, pom, etc.) binds goals to the lifecycle phases by default.  The Maven book describes the [lifecycles and bound goals](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html). The `maven-core` artifact includes the configuration file: [`/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/artifact-handlers.xml`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-3/trunk/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/artifact-handlers.xml?revision=1244153&view=markup).

Answer (score 2):

The default phase of a goal depends on the plugin you are using. For example the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html) is bound to the package phase. But there are other plugins which are not bound to any phase. In those cases you have to define the phase yourself.