# when referring to a maven plugin, if <executions> element is not present, which goal will be executed?

Tags: maven

let's say the plugin has several goals inside. 
for example:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </plugin>
</pulgins>
```

or like this(no executions tag, just configuration tag):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <greeting>Welcome</greeting>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<executions>` are not present, no goal of the plugin will be executed. Simple. But be aware that exist some predefined bindings between plugins' goals and build phases that result from lifecycle definition and that results from artifact's packaging type. So, you don't have to bind `maven-compiler-plugin`'s `compile` and `testCompile` goals to proper phases since they are already bound in lifecycle definition of most packaging types (like `jar` or `war`). But this `hello-maven-plugin`, that probably you just created, needs such binding since no one knows it has to be executed. Also, be aware that plugins' mojos (goals) can define their default binding to lifecycle phase, so sometimes you can see only goal specified in `<execution>` definition without phase.

Comment: Is there a way that maven can find the correct goal based on the configured parameters? (like the 2nd code snippet in my question).

Comment: I don't this so. This configuration stuff are just values that need to be injected into Mojo (Java class that represents plugin's goal) fields by Plexus. To start execution of Mojo, you need to call specific goal. There is no kind of run-time resolution of things.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't see <executions> tags sometimes because they are inherited from parent poms. Thanks so much.

Comment: [How to identify default goals (if any)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10202118/944849)